# writing spec for method that hits a web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm writing a spec to verify that my `Video` model will create a proper thumbnail for a vimeo video when it is created. It looks something like this:

```
    it "creates thumbnail url" do
      vimeo_url = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/12345"
      vid = Factory.build(:video, video_url:vimeo_url)
      # thumbnail created when saved
      vid.save!

      expect do
        URI.parse(vid.thumbnail_url)
      end.to_not raise_error
    end
```

The problem is that my test is super slow because it has to hit vimeo.com. So I'm trying to stub the method that calls to the server. So two questions:

1) Is this the correct way/time to stub something

2) If yes, how do I stub it? In my `Video` model I have a method called `get_vimeo_thumbnail()` that hits vimeo.com. I want to stub that method. But if in my spec I do `vid.stub(:get_vimeo_thumbnail).and_return("http://someurl.com")` it doesn't work. When I run the test it still hits vimeo.com.

Comment: You need to decide what you're really testing. If you're doing an integration test with a remote host, fine...but I *think* you're really just testing thumbnail creation, so you need video fixture data and stubs for your retrievals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VCR gem](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr) is probably worth considering. It hits the real Web service first time you run it and records the response so that it can be replayed next time you run the test (making subsequent tests fast).

I can't see anything wrong with the stub call you are making if you are calling `stub` before `save!`.

Answer (score 0):

I also second the use of the 'vcr' gem.

There's also a (pro)-episode of Railscast available about VCR:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/291-testing-with-vcr

VCR can be used to record all outgoing webservice calls into "cassettes" (fixtures) that will be replayed when the tests are run again. So you get the initial set of "real-world" responses but will not hit the remote api anymore.

It also has options to do "on demand" requests when there is no recorded response available locally, and also to make explicit "live" requests.

You can, and should, run tests agains the live endpoint from time to time to verify.